# Input data from master file to multiple worksheets selecting a specific sheet for each

Tags: vba, excel

I’m relatively new in VBA, and currently I’m working on a macro in `Master_file.xlsm`, which contains multiple ranges of data that have to fill several `.xlsb` files in a folder.

Sheet `Control` contains in `A2` the Folder path, which contains all the `.xlsb` files to be filled, and column `D` the file names.

Sheet `Churn` contains at column `A` the same file names, followed by its respective range to be paste at the `.xlsb` file.

This is all I have so far.

```
Sub Fill_NNAs()

  Dim FilePath As String
  Dim iCell As String
  Dim BC As String

  Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Control").Activate
  LastRow = Range("D2").End(xlDown).Row
  intRowCount = LastRow
  FilePath = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value

  For i = 2 To intRowCount
    iCell = Cells(i, 4).Value
    BC = Cells(i, 3).Value
    Worksheets("Churn").Activate
    Columns("A:A").Select
    x = Selection.Find(What:=BC, After:=ActiveCell,     LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(3, 64)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=FilePath & iCell, ReadOnly:=False,     UpdateLinks:=0
    ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever
    Sheets("Summary_ARD").Select
    Range("C89:BN91").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Workbooks("Master_file.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Control").Select

  Next

  MsgBox "Completed successfully!"

End Sub
```

As you can see, my loop goes to sheet `Control`, get the first file name, searches for it on `Churn`, copies its respective range, open `Filename.xlsb`, activated `Summary_ARD` sheet, paste it and goes to the next.

It has been working fine, but now I have a new problem:

Some `xlsb` files have more than one “Summary_ARD” sheet, like `Summary_ARD`, `Summary_ARD (2)`, `Summary_ARD (3)`, and some have `New_ARD` sheet instead of `Summary_ARD`.

So, what my code has to do now when open a new `Filename.xlsb` is:

1. Activate the `Summary_ARD` with the highest number in parenthesis (Summary_ARD (5) instead of (4), etc).
2. If there is no sheet `Summary_ARD (number)`, activate `Summary_ARD`.
3. If there is no sheet `Summary_ARD`, activate `New_ARD`.
4. For all itens above, it has to look only in the visible sheets.

Any ideas?

Comment: BTW- your English is better than many native American English speakers. If you hadn't said anything, I'd have not known.

Comment: In general yes, but not always. Are you thinking about trying something with the "position" (order) of the sheet? You're welcome! But I was thinking about something like a descending loop counter, like Summary_ARD (i).activate, but I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: You could run the function in my answer on a countdown if you'd like, but that's not the way I went with it.

Comment: I added that idea at the bottom of my answer - it's actually a much better solution than my original one.

Comment: Oh sorry, i forgot the refresh button haha. I'm gonna try this one.

Answer (score 0):

If whatever your target sheet is is the last sheet in the WB, you can just reference it by its `.index` number - the last one being `sheets.count` -

Oh, I restructured your code so you're not using `.selection` or `.activate`

```
Sub Fill_NNAs()
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim FilePath As String
FilePath = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value

Dim iCell As String
Dim BC As String

Dim rngSearch As Range

Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = Range("D2").End(xlDown).Row

Dim wsControl As Worksheet
wsControl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Control")

Dim wsChurn As Worksheet
wsChurn -ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Churn")


For i = 2 To lastrow
    iCell = wsControl.Cells(i, 4).Value
    BC = wsControl.Cells(i, 3).Value

Set rngSearch = wsChurn.Columns(1).Find(What:=BC, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)


Set rngSearch = Range(rngSearch.Offset(1, 1), rngSearch.Offset(3, 64))


Workbooks.Open Filename:=FilePath & iCell, ReadOnly:=False, UpdateLinks:=0
ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("C89:BN91") = rngSearch

ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=True

Next

MsgBox "Completed successfully!"

End Sub
```

Otherwise, you might need to get a little tricky with something like this -

```
Sub testb()
Dim j As Integer
j = 0
Dim wsDest As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If InStr(1, ws.Name, "(") Then
        If Mid(ws.Name, InStr(1, ws.Name, "(") + 1, 1) > j Then
            j = Mid(ws.Name, InStr(1, ws.Name, "(") + 1, 1)
        End If
    End If
Next

    If j = 0 Then
        If SheetExists("Summary_ARD") Then
            wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary_ARD")
            Else: wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New_ARD")
            GoTo label
        End If
    End If

    Set wsDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary_ARD(" & j & ")")
label:
 'do stuff with wsdest

End Sub

Function SheetExists(strWSName As String) As Boolean
    Dim ShTest As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ShTest = Worksheets(strWSName)
    If Not ShTest Is Nothing Then SheetExists = True
End Function
```

---

For your loop to find the sheet, this might work

```
Sub findsheet()
Dim i As Integer
Dim shTest As Worksheet

For i = 1 To 20
On Error GoTo label
Set shTest = Worksheets("Summary_ARD(" & i & ")")

Next
label:
    If i > 1 Then
        Set shTest = Worksheets("Summary_ARD(" & i - 1 & ")")
        GoTo label3
    End
On Error GoTo label2
    Set shTest = Worksheets("Summary_ARD")
    GoTo label3

label2:
    Set shTest = Worksheets("New_ARD")
    GoTo label3

label3:
'do stuff

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! My code looks much more classy now! I'm not sure how to incorporate your Sub testb () in my current code, keeping my loop i. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i'm being dumb (probably), but I just put your loop in the place of mine old Sheets("Summary_ARD").Select, and it doesn't work. I got stuck in the "label" line.

```
    Sub Fill_NNAs()

    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim iCell As String
    Dim BC As String

    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Control").Activate
    LastRow = Range("D2").End(xlDown).Row
    intRowCount = LastRow
    FilePath = ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value

    For i = 2 To intRowCount
    iCell = Cells(i, 4).Value
    BC = Cells(i, 3).Value
   Worksheets("Churn").Activate
   Columns("A:A").Select
    x = Selection.Find(What:=BC, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(3, 64)).Select
    Selection.Copy Workbooks.Open FileName:=FilePath & iCell, ReadOnly:=False,     UpdateLinks:=0 ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever

    On Error GoTo label
    Set shTest = Worksheets("Summary_ARD(" & i & ")")

    Next
    label:
    If i > 2 Then
        Set shTest = Worksheets("Summary_ARD(" & i - 1 & ")")
        GoTo label3
    End
    On Error GoTo label2
    Set shTest = Worksheets("Summary_ARD")
    GoTo label3

    label2:
    Set shTest = Worksheets("New_ARD")
    GoTo label3

    label3:
    Range("C89:BN91").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Workbooks("Master_file.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Control").Select

    Next

    MsgBox "Completed successfully!"

    End Sub
```

Oh sorry, I don't use your re-writed code.